# Finding non-trivial $\textbf{A} \in \mathbb{K}^{3 \times 3}$ such that $\textbf{A}^2 = 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I was requested to find a non-trivial $\textbf{A} \in \mathbb{K}^{3 \times 3}$ such that $\textbf{A}^2 = 0$ where $\mathbb{K}$ is a field and $\mathbb{K^{3 \times 3}}$ is a $\mathbb{K}$-algebra. For $2\times 2$ dimensions the problem is not that complicated. One must simply observe that, for

$$\textbf{A}=\begin{bmatrix}
        a & b \\ c & d
    \end{bmatrix}$$

we have that $\textbf{A}^2=0$ only for solutions of the system

\begin{equation*}
    S =
    \begin{cases}
        a^2 + bc = 0 \\
        ab + bd  = 0 \\
        ca + dc = 0 \\ 
        cb + d^2 =0\\
    \end{cases}
\end{equation*}

Since we are not concerned with the general case, letting $a=1, b=1$ arbitrarily gives solutions $d=c=-1$ and

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ -1 & -1 \end{bmatrix}$$

solves the problem. ($\mathbb{K}$ is a field it has an identity element for $\cdot$ and such element has an additive inverse: arbitrarily using $1$ and $-1$ is justified.)

Now, the *only* way I was able to deal with $3 \times 3$ matrices was to extend the result found using $2\times 2$ matrices. Indeed, it is easy to observe that

$$\textbf{B}:=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0\\ -1 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 &0 &0 \end{bmatrix}$$

satisfies $\textbf{B}^2=0$. Although this solves the problem (the matrix is non-trivial), I was wondering whether there is some other way to build a $3\times 3$ matrix whose square is $0$. One that does not deppend on finding a $2 \times 2$ matrix with such property. I tried direct approaches, such as the one used for building the $2 \times 2$ matrix, but the associated system of equations is overwhelming.

Comment: A more "standard" approach: take a $0$ matrix, and introduce a $1$ somewhere off the diagonal, e.g. $$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: By the theory of Jordan normal forms (which is applicable here for any field, as the characteristic polynomial splits into linear factors), there's only one such matrix up to similarity, the one given in the above comment.

Answer (score -1):

A general solution with Jordan form:

Note that $A^2=0$ implies that $A$ is nilpotent of index $2$ (I assume that $A\neq 0$). This fact means that $A$ is similar to $J=\left(\begin{array} 00 & 0 & 0\\ 1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 &0\end{array}\right)$, because $A$ is a $3\times3$ matrix.

Ie, $A=C^{-1}JC$ where $C$ is an invertible matrix.